# Include images in CSV/KML file

Tags: csv, kml, openlayers-3

I'm working with OpenLayers 3 and I want to include images in KML file in order to show them inside the point on the map.

1. I created this csv file:

[image]

2. I converted it to KML file using https://batchgeo.com
3. The structure of the KML file:

   ```
       <kml xmlns='http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2'>
           <Document>
               <name>Logos2</name><Placemark>
          <styleUrl>#0</styleUrl>
                      <name>A</name>               
                      <ExtendedData>
                           <Data name='logo'>
                           <value>logos/a.png</value>
                           </Data>
                      </ExtendedData>
                      <address></address>
                      <Point>
                       <coordinates>44.72,14.78,0</coordinates>
                      </Point>
                   </Placemark>
                   <Placemark>
   ```

   .
   .
   .
4. in code:

   electedTextStyleFunction(feature.get('value'))

If I replaced 'value' with 'name', it shows successfully on each point. but when i keep 'value', nothing shows. Any idea?

Comment: Put the whole code in plunckr? or give the whole code for `electedTextStyleFunction` method?

Comment: @SumanthShastry sorry here is the example I'm following http://www.acuriousanimal.com/thebookofopenlayers3/chapter05_05_features_under_pointer.html

Comment: look into the below link it might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35248647/how-do-i-access-a-nested-tag-in-a-kml-in-openlayers